How to solve: The endpoint only accepts POST requests. Received a GET request
i have tried implementing microsoft login in a flutter app with firebase. After login in i get the following error The endpoint only accepts POST requests. Received a GET request. and the user is not correctly redirected to my app. When reopening my app, i am successfully logged in.
I used the code:
main.file
import 'package:aad_oauth/model/config.dart';
import 'package:firmparking/pages/General/InitialiseScreen.dart';
import 'package:firmparking/pages/General/RequestWaiting.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firmparking/pages/General/HomePage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
import 'classes/Admin.dart';
import 'classes/UserRequest.dart';
import 'general/functions.dart';
import 'general/functionsFirebaseRead.dart';
import 'general/functionsFirebaseWrite.dart';
import 'pages/General/Login.dart';
import 'package:platform/platform.dart';

//BUILD BEFEHLE:
//WEB: flutter build web
//IOS: flutter build ipa
//ANDROID: flutter clean & flutter build appbundle

void main() async {
  final platform = LocalPlatform();

  FirebaseOptions options = const FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: "xxx",
    authDomain: "xxx.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "xxx",
    storageBucket: "xxx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "175732871753",
    appId: "xxx",
    measurementId: "xxx",
  );

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  if (kIsWeb || platform.isAndroid) {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(options: options);
  } else {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
  }
//      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
  initializeDateFormatting();
  //PushNotificationService().initNotifications();
  //addLockFieldToParkingSpots();
  //test
  runApp(const FirmParking());
}

final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

class FirmParking extends StatelessWidget {
  static Config config = Config(
    tenant: "common",
    clientId: "xxx",
    scope:
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.ReadWrite offline_access", //offline_access
    redirectUri: "https://webapp.firmparking.de/",
    navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
  );

  const FirmParking({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color canvasColor = Colors.white;
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "FirmParking",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: const [
        Locale('de'),
      ],
      // Set the initial locale to German (Germany)
      locale: const Locale('de'),
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: false,
        canvasColor: canvasColor,
        dialogBackgroundColor: canvasColor,
        cardTheme: const CardTheme(
          surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        dialogTheme: DialogTheme(
          backgroundColor: canvasColor,
          surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        fontFamily: "Helvetica Neue",
      ),
      home: StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, authSnapshot) {
          final user = authSnapshot.data;
          if (user != null) {
            if (authSnapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('Error: ${authSnapshot.error}');
            } else {
              return FutureBuilder<Admin?>(
                future: getAdmin(user.uid),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Admin?> dataSnapshot) {
                  if (dataSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return returnLoadingWidget(Colors.white);
                  } else {
                    if (dataSnapshot.hasError) {
                      return const Text('Something went wrong main 0');
                    }
                    if (!dataSnapshot.hasData) {
                      //return const Text('Something went wrong kkkkkkk');
                      // USER IS NOT REGISTERED YET, CHECK IF COMPANY IS REGISTERED - IF SO OPEN WAITING SCREEN
                      // - IF NOT GIVE BACK ERROR MESSAGE
                      return FutureBuilder<List<Admin>?>(
                        future: getAdmins(),
                        builder: (context,
                            AsyncSnapshot<List<Admin>?> adminSnapshot) {
                          if (adminSnapshot.connectionState ==
                              ConnectionState.waiting) {
                            return returnLoadingWidget(Colors.white);
                          } else {
                            if (adminSnapshot.hasError) {
                              return const Text('Something went wrong main 1');
                            }
                            if (!adminSnapshot.hasData) {
                              return const Text('Something went wrong main 2');
                            }
                            List<Admin> admins = adminSnapshot.data!;
                            bool companyExists = false;
                            String? adminID;
                            Admin? adminCache;
                            for (var admin in admins) {
                              if (admin.companies.contains(getDomainOfEmail(
                                  user.email!.toLowerCase()))) {
                                companyExists = true;
                                adminID = admin.adminID;
                                adminCache = admin;
                              }
                            }
                            if (companyExists) {
                              Admin admin = admins.firstWhere(
                                  (admin) => admin.adminID == adminID);
                              if (admin.acceptAzureUserAutomatically) {
                                return InitialiseScreen(
                                  admin: adminCache!,
                                  userID: user.uid,
                                  needForCallAcceptAutomatically: true,
                                  request: UserRequest(
                                      email: user.email!,
                                      userID: user.uid,
                                      adminID: admin.adminID),
                                );
                              } else {
                                addUserRequest(
                                    context, adminID!, user.uid, user.email!);
                                return RequestWaiting(
                                    admin: adminCache!, userID: user.uid);
                              }
                            } else {
                              FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.delete();
                              Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                  msg: "Dein Unternehmen ist nicht registriert",
                                  toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                                  timeInSecForIosWeb: 3,
                                  textColor: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 16.0);
                              return const Login();
                            }
                          }
                        },
                      );
                    } else {
                      navigatorKey.currentState!
                          .popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
                      Admin admin = dataSnapshot.data!;
                      //migrateData();
                      return HomePage(admin: admin);
                    }
                  }
                },
              );
            }
          } else {
            return const Login();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


Login.file
import 'package:email_validator/email_validator.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as fire;
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../general/functions.dart';
import '../../general/functionsFirebaseWrite.dart';
import '../../main.dart';
import '../../theme/colors.dart';
//import 'dart:io' show Platform;

class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({super.key});

  @override
  State<Login> createState() => LoginState();
}

class LoginState extends State<Login> {
  late String? errorPassword = null;
  late String? errorEmail = null;
  late bool passwordVisible;
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    passwordVisible = false;
  }

  Future<void> onLoginClicked() async {
    setState(() {
      errorEmail = null;
      errorPassword = null;
    });
    showLoaderDialog(context);
    try {
      await fire.FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailController.text.trim(),
        password: passwordController.text.trim(),
      ); //LOGIC THAT HANDLES THE LOGIN IS IN THE STREAM BUILDER OF THE main.dart WIDGET TREE
      navigatorKey.currentState!.popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
    } on fire.FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
      navigatorKey.currentState!.popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
      giveBackErrorMessage(error.message!);
    }
  }

  Future<fire.UserCredential?> onMicrosoftLoginClicked() async {
    final microsoftProvider = fire.MicrosoftAuthProvider();
    microsoftProvider.setCustomParameters({'prompt': 'select_account'});
    microsoftProvider.addScope('User.Read'); // Request mandatory permission
    showLoaderDialog(context);

    try {
      if (kIsWeb) {
        // Web platform
        final credential =
            await fire.FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithPopup(microsoftProvider);
        Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
        return credential;
      } else {
        // Mobile platform
        Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
        final credential = await fire.FirebaseAuth.instance
            .signInWithProvider(microsoftProvider);
        return credential;
      }
    } on fire.FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
      Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
      giveBackErrorMessage(error.message!);
      return null;
    } catch (error) {
      Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
      giveBackErrorMessage('An unexpected error occurred: ${error.toString()}');
      return null;
    }
  }

  giveBackErrorMessage(String error) {
    String errorMess;
    if (error ==
        "The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.") {
      errorMess =
          "Passwort ist falsch. Oder das Konto ist mit Microsoft verknüpft.";
      setState(() {
        errorPassword = errorMess;
      });
    } else if (error ==
        "There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. "
            "The user may have been deleted.") {
      errorMess = "Email ist nicht bekannt.";
      setState(() {
        errorEmail = errorMess;
      });
    } else if (error ==
        "Access to this account has been temporarily disabled due "
            "to many failed login attempts. You can immediately restore it by resetting "
            "your password or you can try again later.") {
      //Utils.showSnackbar(error.message);
      errorMess = "Account temporär gesperrt. Später erneut versuchen";
      setState(() {
        errorEmail = errorMess;
      });
    } else if (error ==
        "An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address.") {
      errorMess =
          "Diese Email ist mit einem FirmParking-Konto verknüpft. Bitte loggen sie sich hier ein.";
      setState(() {
        errorEmail = errorMess;
      });
    } else {
      print(error);
      errorMess = "Fehler beim anmelden. Erneut versuchen.";
      setState(() {
        errorEmail = errorMess;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 60),
        child: Wrap(
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 150),
                Image.asset(
                  'assets/logo_round.png', // Replace with your own image
                  width: 180,
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 80),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 250,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    controller: emailController,
                    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                    validator: (email) {
                      email != null && !EmailValidator.validate(email)
                          ? "Email falsch formatiert"
                          : null;
                      return null;
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Email',
                      errorText: errorEmail,
                      errorMaxLines: 3,
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
                      labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                        color: CustomColor.darkBlueColor,
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                      ),
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 5,
                        horizontal: 20,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 250,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    controller: passwordController,
                    obscureText: !passwordVisible,
                    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                    validator: (pwd) {
                      pwd != null && pwd.length < 6
                          ? "Min. 6 Zeichen eingeben"
                          : null;
                      return null;
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          passwordVisible
                              ? Icons.visibility
                              : Icons.visibility_off,
                          color: CustomColor.blueColor,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            passwordVisible = !passwordVisible;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                        color: CustomColor.darkBlueColor,
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      ),
                      errorText: errorPassword,
                      errorMaxLines: 2,
                      labelText: 'Passwort',
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                      ),
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 5,
                        horizontal: 20,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      if (EmailValidator.validate(
                          emailController.text.trim())) {
                        onForgetPasswordClicked(
                            context, emailController.text.trim());
                      } else {
                        setState(() {
                          errorEmail = "Geben sie eine valide Email ein";
                        });
                      }
                    },
                    child: const Text(
                      'Passwort vergessen?',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: CustomColor.darkBlueColor,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 40),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 250,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () => onLoginClicked(),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: CustomColor.darkBlueColor,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      ),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 10,
                        horizontal: 40,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: const Text(
                        'LOGIN',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 40),
                Visibility(
                  visible: true,
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      onMicrosoftLoginClicked();
                    },
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        Image.asset(
                          'assets/microsoft.png', // Replace with Microsoft logo
                          width: 20,
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 10),
                        const Text(
                          'LOGIN MIT MICROSOFT',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


I have setup my Project according to this documentation:
Authenticate Using Microsoft on Android
While IOS and WEB works well, i get the following error when login in on an android device. When going back to the app, i am successfully logged in. The only solution to this problem i have found, is disabling the setting Block third-party cookies and site data. I dont want all my users having to do this. What user experience would that be?
When adding the following code to my manifest:
<activity android:name="com.firebase.ui.auth.KickoffActivity"
     android:exported="true">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
         <data android:scheme="msauth"
             android:host="<packageName>"
        <!--android:pathPrefix="/<SHA2>" /> -->
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

i get this error instead:
Unable to process request due to missing initial state. This may happen if browser sessionStorage is inaccessible or accidentally cleared. Some specific scenarios are - 1) Using IDP-Initiated SAML SSO. 2) Using signInWithRedirect in a storage-partitioned browser environment.
Does anyone have have an idea where this error originates from? Does that come from an mistake in the setup for android platforms in the azure ad portal or is that a front end problem.
I appreciate any help, cheers!

Can you share the complete code in the question or GitHub repo?

updated the question and added the used code @DasariKamali


i get the following error The endpoint only accepts POST requests. Received a GET request.

Instead of using a browser-based sign-in flow, we could implement native sign-in using the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) for Flutter.
pubspec.yaml:
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^2.8.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.6.0

main.dart:
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Microsoft Login')),
        body: SignInScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Microsoft sign-in using OAuthProvider from Firebase:
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignInScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignInScreenState createState() => _SignInScreenState();
}

class _SignInScreenState extends State<SignInScreen> {
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<User?> signInWithMicrosoft() async {
    try {
      // Create a new provider
      OAuthProvider microsoftProvider = OAuthProvider('microsoft.com');

      // Set the required scopes for Microsoft Graph API
      microsoftProvider.setScopes([
        'user.read', // Basic user info scope
        'openid',
        'profile',
        'email',
      ]);

      // Trigger the sign-in flow
      final UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithPopup(microsoftProvider);

      // Retrieve the user from the userCredential
      final User? user = userCredential.user;

      if (user != null) {
        // User is signed in
        print('Sign-in successful: ${user.email}');
        return user;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error signing in with Microsoft: $e');
    }

    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          User? user = await signInWithMicrosoft();
          if (user != null) {
            // User successfully signed in
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(content: Text('Signed in as ${user.email}')),
            );
          }
        },
        child: Text('Sign in with Microsoft'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Identifiers:


Use Chrome Custom Tabs or an in-app WebView to handle the authentication process.

Sign-In:

